# Using a command inside a sed substitution

Tags: bash, sed, command-substitution

I am trying to use sed to replace a sequence of the same characters with the amount of characters in that sequence, but somehow something goes wrong.

I am trying the following:

```
echo aaabbdd | sed -e 's/a*/'"`wc -m &`/"
```

But this returns `0bbdd` while I would like it to return `3bbdd`.

I don't really know what exactly goes wrong sed seems to know what to replace and tries to execute the wc command, but somehow wc counts something empty? I am out of ideas of how to solve this problem, can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: @Theophrastus, it's called "command substitution" and it's a standard shell feature; has nothing to do with Sed.  However, the standard syntax for it is `"$(somecommand)"`; the backtick form is discouraged, deprecated and only kept for backward compatibility.

Comment: Actually, just looked closer...@Chocolate_Althea, you can't *pass text* from Sed into a shell command substitution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is possible indeed, but only with GNU sed,
using the **e** command. So if you don't mind possible portability issues, you can give it a try.

E.g. your example will look something like this:

```
>echo aaabbdd | sed -e 's/a*/echo `echo -n & | wc -m`/;e'
3bbdd
```

if you remove the **;e**, you will see an intermediate command (which helps understand why there are two echo'es)

```
echo `echo -n aaa | wc -m`bbdd
```

If you want to replace multiple matches, this could be more tricky, but still can be done by chaining substitutions:

```
>echo aabbaadd | sed -re 's/a+/`echo -n &|wc -m`/g;s/.*/echo &/;e'
2bb2dd
```

And certainly there are better tools for your task, such as *awk*, which features a built-in *length()* function.

References:

- GNU Sed Manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands

P.S.

Also take a note that if your input data contains quotes, you will have to escape them carefully, or temporarily replace them (i.e. with sed y/// command) for this to work.

Comment: Thank you!
And I'll definitely have a look at awk as well, but I'm fairly new to using the command line, so I have no idea how awk works yet ;)