# Script to convert epoch time to human readable format

Tags: awk, sed, scripting, date

I have a file which contain multiple rows. Some rows represent date and time but that time is in Epoch format. I have tried using some command but that command converted all of the numeric digits. I want to convert only what is applicable.
Same file is as below :-

```
cat FORMATTED 
=============================================================
0='917598936722' 395='1529313008' 391='0' 165='0' 142='0' 131='Status_Pending'
=============================================================

0='917598936722'    :MSISDN  
131='Status_Pending':PROMO_TP3_STATUS  
142='0'             :USAGE_COUNT_3_STATUS  
165='0'             :EBUCKET_USAGE_TS_3  
391='0'             :PROM_3_END_TIMESTAMP  
395='1529313008'    :Date_TC1  
396=='1529313008'   :TC2
```

I need to convert the epoch time present in rows `Date_TC1` and `TC2`. Similar to this there are many more rows and I don't which row represent Epoch date/time; but where this date/time is present in Epoch format, I need to convert to human readable format.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a timestamp in Unix epoch format is just an integer.  There is no way to say "this integer is not a timestamp" unless you give restrictions on the value of the integer (such as "it has to be 1500000000 or larger (after July 14, 2017, 02:40 UTC)".

Answer (score 1):

```
cat conv.awk

/Date_TC1/||/TC2/   {
    split($0, r, "'")
    print(r[1], strftime("%c", r[2]), r[3], r[4])
    next
    }

{ print }

awk -f conv.awk src.txt
=============================================================
0='917598936722' 395='1529313008' 391='0' 165='0' 142='0' 131='Status_Pending'
=============================================================

0='917598936722'    :MSISDN  
131='Status_Pending':PROMO_TP3_STATUS  
142='0'             :USAGE_COUNT_3_STATUS  
165='0'             :EBUCKET_USAGE_TS_3  
391='0'             :PROM_3_END_TIMESTAMP  
395= Mon 18 Jun 2018 11:10:08 AM CEST     :Date_TC1   
396== Mon 18 Jun 2018 11:10:08 AM CEST    :TC2
```

Comment: Since the question doesn't specify Linux or a GNU environment, I'll just point out that `strftime` in awk is a GNU extension to [the standard awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands), try this:

```
sed -re 's/([0-1][0-6][0-9]{8})/$(date -d @&)/g;
         /date -d/ s/\x27/\\\x27/g;
         /date -d/ s/\$[^(]/\\$\(/g;
         /date -d/ s/.*/echo &/e' FORMATTED
```

Explanation:

- `s/([0-1][0-6][0-9]{8})/$(date -d @&)/g`: Replace all timestamps (10 digits with 00 - 16 as first numbers) with `$(date -d @<timestamp>)`
- `/date -d/`: Only run the following commands when `date -d` was found in the line (= lines that we changed in the previous step)
- `s/\x27/\\\x27/g`: Replace all `'` with `\'` so that everything in between **will** be interpreted in the last step.
- `s/\$[^(]/\\$\(/g;`: Replace all `$` that are not followed by a `(` with `\$`, so that these will not be interpreted as variable in the last step
- `s/.*/echo &/;e`: Execute (`e`) an `echo` on the whole line (`.*`)

> Note: This behaves similar to `eval`, executing everything that is in the original file, e.g. `do_something_evil`.

([via](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327450/236063))