# how to embed command substitution in sed?

Tags: bash, sed, command-substitution

from this answer:
[Using a command inside a sed substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327394/using-a-command-inside-a-sed-substitution) there is used this to make command substitution:

```
echo aaabbdd | sed -e 's/a*/echo `echo -n & | wc -m`/;e'
```

When I shell use double quotes to expand bash commands (as suggested in comments: `sed '$a'"$(some commands)" somefile` and when to use embedded commands in sed (as from the example above - from the link) - because I can obviously use `&` (sed match) in outer bash command. So which use when?

Comment: `&` is not placing the `echo` command in the background - it's substituted by the matched portion (in this case, `aaa`) before the pattern space is passed to the shell for execution

Comment: try `sed '$a'"$(alias so)"` however, any escape sequences like `\t` in the content of the command output will get expanded, and you cannot have literal newlines in that output

Comment: @steeldriver I do not understand, can you please elaborate the `substituted by the matched portion`, from when does `&` substitute any portion and which portion? From preceding command? I do no understand. give some exmaple used in bash

Comment: also, if you wanted to use `-i` option with that `alias` example, you do not need `sed` at all, `alias so >> filename` will append the output of the command to the file

Comment: @Sundeep that is not the point, I want to use `sed` with bash commands. Can you still explain the '&' ? Is it just sed substitution or is it bash feature?

Comment: `echo 'foo 123 bar' | sed -E 's/[0-9]+/(&)/'` will give `foo (123) bar` because `&` in replacement section means you are telling sed to use the entire matched portion, which is `123` in this example..

Comment: Everyone: please post answers to answer the question instead of discussing it in comments.

Comment: But I can reference the match porion with `\1` or does that mean only for matched group?

Comment: @terdon, the ii) -  I do not ask about  `-e` as option, but `e` as action at the end of sed - `sed 'somecommand; e'`

Comment: Ah, sorry, since you had both that wasn't clear. But it still should be a separate question, so thank you for editing!

Answer (score -2):

See the following script:

```
echo "DATE_REPLACE_ME_hh" | sed -e "s/DATE_REPLACE_ME/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')/g"
```

Comment: This does not appear to address the issue in question: when to use command substitution in the replacement part of the substitution and when to use the special GNU `sed` flag `/e`.